# Why programmatically created clicks are excluded in the Vuetify ClickOutside Directive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a very specific scenario in my hands to solve. I'm using FastClick to overcome the old
~300ms delay on clicks on mobile.
The project is an old Cordova app, and FastClick basically listens to touch events to 
programmatically create click events. But the issue comes with Vuetify Click Outside directive,
which exist to close multiple menus and components through the app, this directive chooses to
ignore click events that are not trusted (event.isTrusted) so basically my components don't close
when user clicks.
I have tried to transpile Vuetify locally as the last resort, which I'm struggling with.
Next is the link to the Vuetify Source Code on the version I'm using (2.1.18).
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/v2.2.18/packages/vuetify/src/directives/click-outside/index.ts#L35-L37

```
  // Vuetify Source Code

  // If click was triggered programmaticaly (domEl.click()) then
  // it shouldn't be treated as click-outside
  // Chrome/Firefox support isTrusted property
  // IE/Edge support pointerType property (empty if not triggered
  // by pointing device)
  if (('isTrusted' in e && !e.isTrusted) ||
    ('pointerType' in e && !e.pointerType)
  ) return
```

If someone could tell me how to overwrite this behavior or any kind of solution, it would help me a lot.